# Is there any open source Java program that can save .mid file as .wav file?

Tags: java, wav

Now I'm using iTunes to convert .mid file to .wav file, I wonder if there is a way that I can do this from my Java program, any open source Java program that can read in a .mid file and save it as .wav file ?

Comment: You need a MIDI synthesizer with instruments.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to look at [JFugue](http://www.jfugue.org/index.html) and [Frinika](http://frinika.appspot.com/).